# How are regression trees fitted in gradient boosting for classification?

Tags: decision-trees, gradient-boosting-decision-trees

What I understood is that even gradient boosting for binary classification uses regression trees. The first value we calculate is constant = log(odds).
For the rest of the trees, we try to fit regression trees on the residuals.
But how do we fit the trees? Or how is the best splitting feature calculated? Is it the same as decision trees for regression or something else?